# How to set frequency and duty cycle of Timer1 in 16bit P&F correct PWM

Tags: timer, frequency, avr, 16-bit

I am using a 328P (Running on the internal 8mhz) to generate a Square wave at around 111K hz or 120K hz with and adjustable duty cycle.

I'm fairly new to doing this level of hardware manipulation so please excuse my ignorance, I spent 3 days looking online and in the datasheet but I'm afraid my understanding of what the acronyms and abbreviations mean is still too limited.

So far I have come up with the following code after doing the research online and in the datasheet. But I feel like I'm missing something, What register manipulates frequency and what register manipulates duty cycle in (Datasheet 20.12.5) Phase and Frequency Correct PWM Mode?

```
void setup(){
    DDRB |= (1 << DDB1); //Set PB1 as output
    OCR1A = (Unsure of what TOP should be here);
    TCCR1A = (1 << WGM10) | (1 << COM1B0) | (1 << COM1A0);
    TCCR1B = (1 << CS10) | (1 << WGM13);
}
void loop(){
    //manipulate duty cycle with other code here
}
```

What am I missing or what should I be doing differently here?
I tried to use the online AVR Timer Calc to help me get clock ticks needed for that frequency. It says a total of 72 Timer ticks with no prescaler and 16 bit timer would yield a 111Khz (approximate) Square wave. Jumping to 73 or 71 jumps the frequency too much out of the desired range. is there any way to get that closer on an AVR?

Comment: What frequency is your ATmega328P running at?

Comment: 8Mhz internal source.

Comment: What is P&F?  I can't find that string in the datasheet.  Please write out abbreviations.

Comment: 20.12.5. Phase and Frequency Correct PWM Mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research along side a friend of mine who is also an EE and works with embedded systems we came to find the best solution for getting what I needed out of the 328p. I will post the solution below for anyone who is interested and needs something similar.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  //Set Timer1 for around 109Khz signal
  cli();//stop interrupts
  TCCR1A = 0;// set entire TCCR1A register to 0
  TCCR1B = 0;// same for TCCR1B
  TCNT1  = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
  //Set register bits 
  TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(WGM11);
  TCCR1B = _BV(CS10) | _BV(WGM12) | _BV(WGM13);
  ICR1 = 73; // frequency = 8000000/73 = 109.589 kHz
  OCR1A = 0; //0% Duty Cycle or Full Off.
  sei();//allow interrupts
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  OCR1A = 36; //50% Duty Cycle 73/2 = 36.5 Can be changed as needed.
}
```

This code sets the registers for Timer 1 so it shouldn't interfere with millis or other timing functions in the Arduino libraries. I needed to manipulate a specific pin anyways and PB1 (OC1A) (or Arduino digital pin 9) is the pin that this will oscillate.

You can change ICR1 to any value you need based on some simple math,
Your clock frequency divided by the value of the counter equals the approximate frequency produced. OCR1A sets the duty cycle of the signal.

You are limited in the exact frequency but for my needs this worked out OK.
I was still able to use it to drive the transducer I was using.

This was a quick answer to the initial problem and allows me to change the duty cycle as a bonus. I don't remember the exact information on the registers we set, When I have time I will update this answer with the info from the data sheet pertaining to that.

Comment: This is only partially true. How do you know if this gives the correct output? You should use two such signals to show that they are in phase and frequency

Comment: @Amrith I'm not sure what you mean. I posted this in 2018. The code above does exactly what it says, I tested it with my oscilloscope and the project I was working on functioned as designed, generating a signal to run a piezo electric transducer. I was able to control the frequency with ICR1 and the duty cycle with OCR1A. This was a long time ago so I am past this problem now. But for anyone else who is looking for this solution I can confirm with absolute certainty that this does what it says it does. Can you elaborate on what is only partially true though?

Answer (score 2):

In the title, you asked "ATMega328P How to set TIMER1 PWM Frequency".  You tune the frequency by setting the TOP value to what you want it to be.  A smaller TOP value means the counter reaches TOP sooner, so the frequency is higher.  The prescaler and clock source you use for the timer determines how fast it counts up, so that also affects the frequency, what ranges of frequencies are possible, and the resolution you get for setting the frequency.  Your TOP value also determines how much resolution you have when setting the duty cycle, since the duty cycle should be an integer less than or equal to TOP.

Near the bottom of your post, you asked "is there any way to get that closer on an AVR?"  Since your AVR is running at 8 MHz, every frequency you can generate with its timers will be of the form (8 MHz)/N, where N is some integer.  That's because the timers can't do anything or change anything between ticks of the clock source you are supplying to them.  Timer 1 will get a clock tick 8 times per microsecond, and each time that clock tick happens it can advance its count and/or control a PWM pin and/or fire an interrupt.  I think you already figured this out using the online AVR timer calculator.  Here are some of the achievable PWM frequencies you can get on an AVR running at 8 MHz:

- 8000 kHz / 73 = 109.6 kHz
- 8000 kHz / 72 = 111.1 kHz
- 8000 kHz / 71 = 112.7 kHz

If you need more precise frequency tuning, you need to get a faster clock source in your system one way or another.  You could get a faster microcontroller or maybe figure out how to supply a faster clock as an input to a timer on the microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't really answer any of my questions. From what I understand the Top value determines frequency if you are using CTC mode but not in fast PWM or phase and frequency PWM mode. Maybe I'm wrong on that assumption. What I'm looking for is clarification on the code I posted and possible function I need to add to accomplish the functionality I need. I've already used timer1 in 8 bit CTC mode with a top value of 8 to get close to the frequency I needed but it was not accurate and had a couple errors using an ISR to toggle the PB1 port in two clock cycles.

Comment: I updated my answer with new info about 8 MHz AVRs and made it clear which questions of your I am answering.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your answer. Is the code snippet I posted all that is needed to get what I'm after or do I need to interact with another register to change duty cycle and set frequency independently?

Comment: There are two important registers, OCR1A and OCR1B.  When you configure the timer correctly, one of them is the TOP value (72) and the other is the PWM duty cycle value (between 0 and 72); I forget which is which at the moment but you should be reading the datasheet to determine that.  What mode are you going to use anyway?  You didn't mention it in your question and you mentioned several different modes in your comment above.

Comment: Please mark my answer as the accepted answer if you think I've answered the questions you asked in the original post.  If you need help writing the exact code that generates a working PWM signal, that could be a separate question.

Comment: Well the exact mode I'm trying to use has been added to the title already and is also in the code that I've already put together. I'm not sure if you are actually paying attention to what is written out. I will mark the answer once it fully answers the question. as it stands right now I don't feel it is satisfactory. This question has multiple parts that are all relative to each other. I have the data sheet but unfortunately it does not show how to write the code to do what I want. it just gives you the registers and it doesn't fully describe their use in each mode. it seems kind of vague.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for in the ATmega328P datasheet:
"In phase and frequency correct PWM mode the counter is incremented until the counter value matches either the value in ICR1 (WGM1[3:0]=0x8), or the value in OCR1A (WGM1[3:0]=0x9)."  So the frequency is either determined by ICR1 or OCR1A depending on what you set your WGM1 bits to.  It looks like you have set WGM13 to 1, WGM12 to 0, WGA11 to 0, and WGM10 to 1, so WGM1[3:0] is 0b1001, which is 0x9, indicating that OCR1A would be your frequency register.  You can change those WGM bits if you don't like that.

Comment: You initially posted this question with just a few questions about how to set the frequency and what frequencies your AVR can do, and now it seems like you actually can't generate a PWM at all and you need someone to provide working code. That is a separate question.  You could mark my answer as accepted and then make a new question where you clearly state that you do not know how to generate PWM, but give the complete code you have, along with the expected behavior and the actual behavior, and ask what changes must be made to the code to make it work.